# Self Hosted MS Service Fabric: Deploying Spring Boot to Windows?

Tags: spring-boot, azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric, windows-server-2012-r2

Is it possible to deploy Java (Spring Boot) applications to a Windows 2012 R2 based Service Fabric installation on our own internal network? If so, then how?

Using Linux based servers is not an option for me, but the documentation does not give instructions on creating a Java application using the windows based installation.

I'll be trying a few things out on my own, but it would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can package Java applications on Windows ([on prem](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server/)), as [guest executables](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app/) and run them. They won't be able to use the SDK (actors, services, state).